# How to request CHANGE_WIFI_MULTICAST_STATE permission from flutter

Tags: android, flutter

I have tried using 'permission_handler' package. But it doesn't provide the support for CHANGE_WIFI_MULTICAST_STATE permission.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

just put this in your android manifest

```
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CHANGE_WIFI_MULTICAST_STATE" />
```